# Flutter stuck at "Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'..." when I tried to create an apk

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm fairly new to android studio and flutter. Recently I released a simple app and I used the command `flutter build apk`. An apk was built fairly quickly but the size was a bit more than I expected. Then someone advised me to run the command `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64` and so I did that with my next app. However, terminal is now stuck at `Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...`. There's no cpu usage so I'm sure the app is not being built in the background.

Comment: Sometimes it happens with flutter, it takes longer than usual time to build

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, run `flutter clean`

then `flutter upgrade` (**optional**)

*if you want to release your app in Playstore, then run

`flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64`

otherwise `flutter build apk` will also work

This will help you

Comment: Our customer also got this problem, and I told them you answer, it solved our customer's problem. Thank you :) I did voted up this answer.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you @NgocNam